# Attempting to delete a page in Microsoft Word (VBA) that contains specific text in a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, shapes

I have been developing a macro for Microsoft Word using VBA which is supposed to find certain text within a textbox (shape) and then delete the page that the textbox with that text is found on. Here is my macro:

```
Sub DeletePagesWithSpecificTextBoxText()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim FoundOnPageNumber As Integer
    
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            shp.Select
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "delete this page"
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute
                If .Found Then
                    FoundOnPageNumber = Selection.ShapeRange.Anchor.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
                    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, FoundOnPageNumber
                    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

In order to test this macro - I have a basic ten page document where I have labelled each page in sequence from 1 to 10. Each page has a TextBox which contains the text "delete this page" (this is the text the macro is looking for).

After the macro has been run, the document contains all of the even pages (i.e. 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10) however the odd pages (1, 3, 5, 7 and 9) have been deleted.

Can anyone provide any insight into why it would only be deleting the odd pages?

EDIT:
User **macropod** was a huge help in getting this to work correctly. The complete working macro is shown below:

```
Sub DeletePagesWithSpecificTextBoxText()

    Dim TextFoundOnThisPage As Integer
    Dim DeleteLastPage As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim s As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        For s = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Shapes(s)
                If .Type = msoTextBox Then
                    If InStr(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "delete this page") > 0 Then
                        TextFoundOnThisPage = .Anchor.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
                        
                        If TextFoundOnThisPage = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count And DeleteLastPage = False Then
                            DeleteLastPage = True
                        End If
                        
                        .Delete
                        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, TextFoundOnThisPage
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
    
    If DeleteLastPage Then
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count
        Selection.TypeBackspace
        Selection.TypeBackspace
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

The DeleteLastPage flag is required to ensure there isn't a blank page left at the end of the document *if* a textbox was found on that last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looping though the shapes backwards; otherwise the loop skips the next shape after a deletion. There is also no need to select anything:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim s As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For s = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Shapes(s)
      If .Type = msoTextBox Then
        If InStr(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "delete this page") > 0 Then
          .Anchor.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help macropod.

Iterating backward through the shapes makes sense although I get an error that I encountered earlier this morning:

**Run-time error '5941'
The requested member of the collection does not exist.**

I found that this error came up because I had the textbox selected and I needed to deselect it in order for this line to work:

`.Anchor.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete`

Comment: Most likely you had two or more shapes on the same page. You can either get the shape count for the page so as to decrement the s value correctly when the page is deleted or you could simply employ On Error Resume Next.

Comment: Thanks very much again. My test document contains just one textbox per page. I will experiment some more to see if I can get your macro working however and will post back here with my results :)

Comment: It's not just a question of how many textboxes your document has on a page but of how many shape objects in general it has on a page.

Comment: After a good deal of playing around, I have managed to get it working consistently on a variety of documents. I am not sure exactly how I should upload the code to stack overflow - should I add it to my original question or should I add it as an answer?

Comment: Perhaps just add a comment to explain what you did.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to fir the explanation in the comments section so I have edited the original question to show the final macro.